# Python: TypeVar for multiple arguments at once

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

Is there a way to have a `TypeVar` (or some other format) capture all the arguments of a function? For example, say I want to wrap a general function, such that all its arguments are given within a tuple:

```py
def invoke(f: Callable[..., T], args: Tuple[...]) -> T:
    return f(*args)
```

Only that instead of the ellipsis (`...`), I'll have the static-type inspection enforce the contents of the `Tuple` to be have the same types as the function's arguments.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **Yes**, just not with `TypeVar`. One should use [`ParamSpec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec):

```py
from typing import ParamSpec, TypeVar, Callable
P = ParamSpec('P')
RT = TypeVar('RT')

def invoke(f: Callable[P, RT], args: P.args) -> RT:
    return f(*args)

# Or, makes more sense:

def invoke(f: Callable[P, RT], args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> RT:
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
```

Note that for python < 3.10, one should import it from [`typing_extensions`](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/) rather than `typing`.

Answer (score 1):

You could modify the below to work with your requirements, you'll likely need to add in extra handling.

```py
from typing import Any

class TypeEnforce:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    def __call__(self, *args):
        types = dict(zip(self.func.__annotations__.values(), args))
        for k, v in types.items():
            if k is Any:
                continue
            assert type(v) == k
        self.func(*args)
```

Example

```py
@TypeEnforce
def my_test(x: str, y: int) -> None:
    print(f"'x' is a {type(x).__name__}")


@TypeEnforce
def my_other_test(x: Any):
    return x

my_test("Test", "eight")
my_other_test("Test2")
```

Will result in an `AssertionError` because the function `my_test` takes (`str`, `int`) but is passed (`str`, `str`). There would also be edge cases where a hint of `TypedDict` would always fail because it isn't really a type, rather syntactic sugar for a `dict`.

Comment: That's a nice idea but, unless I'm mistaken, what you wrote will enforce the types at runtime (i.e. dynamic type checking). I'm looking for a similar mechanism to validate the types using `mypy` or better - PyCharm's IDE (i.e. static type-checking / PEP 484).

Comment: Ah okay, it might be worth editing your question to be explicit with that. I can't speak for PyCharm or MyPy but type hinting is just that, hinting, so you might not find what you're after but certainly good luck!

Comment: Thank you anyway. In PyCharm the hints are actually used for code inspection (with "compiler"-warnings) so it's very useful.